# Entity Framework Navigation Property Error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting this error in my .Net MVC 4 web application:

```
The property 'Username' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The 
property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract 
getter and setter.  For collection properties the type must implement 
ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.
```

I am very new to Entity Framework and I can't seem to get around this issue. Here is some code:

```
//DB Context
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithMany(r => r.Users).Map(x => x.MapLeftKey("Username").MapRightKey("RoleName").ToTable("Users_Roles"));
    }  

}

//Entity Classes

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }
    public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsOnLine { get; set; }
    public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLockedOutDate { get; set; }
    public int FailedPasswordAttemptCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart { get; set; }
    public int FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("RoleName")]
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Username;
    }
}

public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Username")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.RoleName;
    }

}

//Repository
public class EFUsersRepository : IUsersRepository
{
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IQueryable<User> Users
    {
        get { return context.Users; }
    }

    public User GetUser(string username) 
    {
        return context.Users.Find(username); //THIS IS WHERE THE CRASH OCCURS
    }
}

//DB Setup
Table Users, Role and Users_Role. Users_Role is a simple linking table with [username, role] columns both of type varchar.

The database tables columns & types match the two classes above (User,Role).
```

I inherited this project which was unfinished but I can't get it to run successfully. Any help understanding what the issue is would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Could you upload the database tables including data types?

Comment: @Win - I made a small update to the question: Table Users, Role and Users_Role. Users_Role is a simple linking table with [username, role] columns both of type varchar. The database tables columns & types match the two classes above (User,Role).

Comment: Normally, **username** or **rolename** should not be **Primary Key**. Without seeing your database, I do not know database error or code first error.

Comment: How do I provide a database? I am not sure how to do that. The User & Role tables have the Username and RoleName as primary keys and in the table Users_Roles they are foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, after commenting out enough items all day long, the the following lines are what caused this error for me:

```
[InverseProperty("RoleName")] //In file User.cs (as shown above)
[InverseProperty("UserName")] //in file Role.cs (as shown above)
```

I am still learning Entity Framework and I don't know why this was the solution, but it stopped the error which I reported above.

I hope that this helps someone else and if anyone wants to help me understand what the issue was in detail, please feel free. I am eager to learn.

Comment: I also noticed **InverseProperty** when I generated the **DataModel** via EF6. However, you did not say what Version of EF you are using, so I just posted how to create DataModel again. Basically, if they are auto-generated code, you need to regenerate them when you update EF. Anyhow, I'm glad that you figured it out!

Comment: **FYI:** Making Username and Rolename as Primary Keys are not good database design practice.

Comment: @Win As stated above, I inherited this project as is and did not design or implement the database in question. It would be more useful to state what the solution or better idea would be in this case than solely to point out the negative.

Comment: I think previous developer *partially* copy the database design from ASP.Net Membership Provider. Ideally, you want **UserId** column in **Users** table and **RoleId** column  in **Roles** table with data type of either uniqueidentifier or int. Then use that **UserId** and **RoleId**  as foreign key in **Users_Role** table. You can read more [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It might be that Entity Framework is updated. Easiest way will be to recreate the DataModel.

Even if the previous programmer did not use Entity Data Mode, you can at least copy the auto generated code such as EFDbContext, Users and Roles classes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried what you said the the generated code matched (almost exactly) the code that we already have.